# Windows server 2016 password hashes

Tags: windows, active-directory, windows-server-2016

how to store passwords of local users (including existing users) in the configuration as a scrypt\bcrypt hash.
I tried configuring it in password policies. But I found nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Local user account password hashes are stored in a local Security Account Manager (SAM) Database located in the registry. They are encrypted using the same encryption and hashing algorithms as Active Directory. The passwords in the supplementalCredentials attribute for local user accounts are also stored in the local SAM Database since Windows Server 2016.

The SAM file location path is : **C:\Windows\System32\config\SAM**

You can also find the same in **HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SAM** in the registry editor.

Reference : [Passwords technical overview | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/security/kerberos/passwords-technical-overview#how-passwords-are-stored-in-windows)